# Swift memory leak while using firebase listener

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, memory-leaks

My Memory Graph shows 2 FeedViewModels even though it should only be one since I only have 1 Feed created in Firebase

If i printObject feedViewModel.text in the init block breakpoint in my FeedRow it shows -> This is a firebase text 5

But when i printObject feedViewModel.text in the breakpoint where the view actually displays the text it shows -> This is a firebase text 4

Here is my function in the firebase repository:
`func fetchAllFeeds(completion: @escaping (Result<[Feed], FirebaseError>) -> Void) {
self.feedIdsListener = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("feeds").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
if let error {
print("Fetch feeds failed: (error)")
completion(.failure(.unknown(error)))
return
}

```
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("Query Snapshot has no documents")
            completion(.failure(.collectioNotFound))
            return
        }
        
        let allFeeds = documents.compactMap { document in
            try? document.data(as: Feed.self)
        }
        
        completion(.success(allFeeds))
    }
}`
```

Here is the function in my FeedsViewModel that generates my [FeedViewModel]
`private func fetchAllFeeds() {
feedRepository.fetchAllFeeds() { [weak self] result in
switch result {
case .success(let allFeeds):
if let user = self?.user {
self?.feeds = allFeeds.compactMap { FeedViewModel($0, withUser: user) }
self?.feeds.sort(by: { $0.updatedAt > $1.updatedAt })

```
                if let feeds = self?.feeds {
                    self?.followedFeeds = feeds.filter { user.following.contains($0.creator) }
                    
                    self?.ownFeeds = feeds.filter { $0.creator == user }
                    
                    self?.usedFeeds = feeds.filter { $0.activeUsers.contains(user) }
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed fetching feeds: \(error)")
        }
    }
}`
```

At this point i generate my FeedRows in my FeedView using the data from the FeedsViewModel
`VStack { ForEach(self.feedsViewModel.feeds) { feed in FeedRow(feed) } } .padding(.horizontal)`

Here is my FeedRow
`struct FeedRow: View {

```
@EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
@StateObject var feedViewModel: FeedViewModel

@State private var showComments = false
@State private var translationActive: Bool = false

private var textIsTranslated: Bool {
    feedViewModel.translatedText != nil
}

init(_ feedViewModel: FeedViewModel) {
    _feedViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: feedViewModel)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 8) {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
            ProfilePictureSmall()
            
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                HStack {
                    Text(self.feedViewModel.creator.realName)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "envelope")
                            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                    })
                }
                Text((!self.translationActive ? self.feedViewModel.text : self.feedViewModel.translatedText) ?? "")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .fontWeight(.thin)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 16) {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feedViewModel.likeFeed()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "heart")
                                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        })
                        Text(String(self.feedViewModel.likes.count))
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showComments = true
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
                                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        })
                        Text(String(self.feedViewModel.comments.count))
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.translationActive.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Text(self.textIsTranslated ? (self.translationActive ? "Show original" : "Translate") : "No Translation")
                        })
                        .disabled(!self.textIsTranslated)
                        
                        Text(self.feedViewModel.createdAtString)
                            .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    }
                    .font(.footnote)
                }
            }
        }
        
        if !self.feedViewModel.images.isEmpty {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ForEach(self.feedViewModel.images, id: \.self) { url in
                        AsyncImage(
                            url: URL(string: url),
                            content: { image in
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(height: 200)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                            },
                            placeholder: {
                                Image(systemName: "network.slash")
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
        }
        
        Divider()
        
        if !self.feedViewModel.richPreviews.isEmpty {
            ForEach(self.feedViewModel.richPreviews) { richLinkPreview in
                RichLinkPreviewView(richPreviewViewModel: richLinkPreview)
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showComments, content: {
        CommentsView()
            .environmentObject(self.feedViewModel)
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
    })
    .onAppear {
        self.feedViewModel.translateText()
    }
    .onChange(of: self.textIsTranslated) {
        if self.textIsTranslated {
            self.translationActive = true
        } else {
            self.translationActive = false
        }
    }
}
```

}`

I already tried [weak self] in the function in the FeedsViewModel in hope it helps but it didnt change anything and the memory leak persists

I fixed it by modyfing the code in the FeedRow like this:
@EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
weak var weakFeedViewModel: FeedViewModel?
@ObservedObject var feedViewModel: FeedViewModel

```
@State private var showComments = false
@State private var translationActive: Bool = false

private var textIsTranslated: Bool {
    feedViewModel.translatedText != nil
}

init(_ feedViewModel: FeedViewModel) {
    weakFeedViewModel = feedViewModel
    _feedViewModel = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: weakFeedViewModel ?? feedViewModel)
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, Fix is in main post

Comment: Great you fixed it! But. when posting questions, please format the code so it's readable using the formatting tools when editing the question and it's also quite long so the code should be reduced to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)